# Problem building AngularJS webapp to android on Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I have a webapp made with HTML, CSS and AngularJS.

I host it on my own server and everything works perfectly.

I installed the cordova, created a project and added the files related to the webapp inside folder www.

Running the app from the command:

```
cordova run browser
```

everything works perfectly.

When running:

```
cordova run android
```

the apk is built. I uploaded this apk to an android and the app just doesn't work.

Here is the index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Exemple</title>

          <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>          
          <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

          <!-- criação do app -->
          <script src="app/app.js"></script>

          <!-- definição das rotas -->
          <script src="routes/routes.js"></script>

          <!-- controllers do app -->
          <script src="controller/DashController.js"></script>
          <script src="controller/DashPainelController.js"></script>  

          <!-- services do app -->
          <script src="services/isAuthenticated.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="DashController">
  <div>
      <a class="navbar-brand" ng-hide="habilitabotao" href="/">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my folder structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/beM8N.png

I tried to debug the app through Android Studio. However, I couldn't find the error in logcat.
Below is my logcat:

```
2020-05-15 12:16:04.574 3814-3814/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-05-15 12:16:04.576 3814-3814/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-05-15 12:16:06.246 3814-3814/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parsoni-1/lib/x86
2020-05-15 12:16:06.447 3814-3814/? I/CordovaLog: Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
2020-05-15 12:16:06.447 3814-3814/? I/CordovaActivity: Apache Cordova native platform version 8.1.0 is starting
2020-05-15 12:16:06.447 3814-3814/? D/CordovaActivity: CordovaActivity.onCreate()
2020-05-15 12:16:07.155 3814-3814/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/Chrome/lib/x86
2020-05-15 12:16:07.165 3814-3814/? I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 51.0.2704.90 (code 275509012)
2020-05-15 12:16:07.248 3814-3814/? I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 12 ms (timestamps 1724-1736)
2020-05-15 12:16:07.250 3814-3814/? I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.90", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.90"
2020-05-15 12:16:07.759 3814-3814/? V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {eb5dc6}
2020-05-15 12:16:07.760 3814-3814/? I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.90", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.90"
2020-05-15 12:16:07.760 3814-3814/? I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2020-05-15 12:16:07.923 3814-3814/? I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
2020-05-15 12:16:07.934 3814-3814/? E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/natives_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/natives_blob_64.bin
2020-05-15 12:16:07.935 3814-3814/? E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin
2020-05-15 12:16:08.641 3814-3814/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x98f3c060: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-05-15 12:16:08.643 3814-3814/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x98f3c060: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x98f26220)
2020-05-15 12:16:08.728 3814-3841/? W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2020-05-15 12:16:08.948 3814-3814/? D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
2020-05-15 12:16:08.959 3814-3814/? W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
2020-05-15 12:16:08.961 3814-3814/? D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
2020-05-15 12:16:08.982 3814-3814/? D/SystemWebViewEngine: CordovaWebView is running on device made by: Google
2020-05-15 12:16:08.990 3814-3814/? D/PluginManager: init()
2020-05-15 12:16:09.050 3814-3814/? D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
2020-05-15 12:16:09.088 3814-3814/? I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
2020-05-15 12:16:09.114 3814-3814/? D/CordovaActivity: Started the activity.
2020-05-15 12:16:09.119 3814-3814/? D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
2020-05-15 12:16:09.354 3814-3856/? E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
2020-05-15 12:16:09.393 3814-3856/com.parsoni I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2020-05-15 12:16:09.680 3814-3856/com.parsoni D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x96584240: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-05-15 12:16:09.681 3814-3856/com.parsoni D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x96584240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x96bf05a0)
2020-05-15 12:16:09.749 3814-3855/com.parsoni I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-05-15 12:16:09.749 3814-3855/com.parsoni D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2020-05-15 12:16:10.146 3814-3855/com.parsoni W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-05-15 12:16:10.146 3814-3855/com.parsoni D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2020-05-15 12:16:10.181 3814-3855/com.parsoni D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x98f3e5e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-05-15 12:16:10.287 3814-3855/com.parsoni D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x98f3e5e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x96bf0050)
2020-05-15 12:16:10.606 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-05-15 12:16:10.774 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:10.789 3814-3855/com.parsoni D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x98f3e5e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x96bf0050)
2020-05-15 12:16:11.123 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageDidNavigate(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
2020-05-15 12:16:11.246 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:11.262 3814-3825/com.parsoni I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 362(21KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 18MB/22MB, paused 14.505ms total 163.363ms
2020-05-15 12:16:11.965 3814-3863/com.parsoni D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-05-15 12:16:16.025 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 3814
2020-05-15 12:16:16.025 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
2020-05-15 12:16:16.026 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
2020-05-15 12:16:16.028 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/Choreographer: Skipped 286 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-05-15 12:16:16.038 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 3814
2020-05-15 12:16:16.040 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js: Line 125 : Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html&p1=-1&p2=
2020-05-15 12:16:16.040 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(125)] "Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html&p1=-1&p2=", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js (125)
2020-05-15 12:16:16.040 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js: Line 11 : Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html&p1=-1&p2=)
2020-05-15 12:16:16.040 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html&p1=-1&p2=)", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js (11)
2020-05-15 12:16:16.047 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js: Line 11 : Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html&p1=-1&p2=
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:7:168
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:164:28
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:138:44
        at m.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:149:147)
        at m.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:152:525)
        at k (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:103:129)
        at V (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:108:205)
        at XMLHttpRequest.A.onerror (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:109:195)
2020-05-15 12:16:16.048 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html&p1=-1&p2=
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:7:168
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:164:28
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:138:44
        at m.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:149:147)
        at m.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:152:525)
        at k (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:103:129)
        at V (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:108:205)
        at XMLHttpRequest.A.onerror (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:109:195)", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js (11)
2020-05-15 12:16:16.110 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:16.123 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(file:///)
2020-05-15 12:16:16.183 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:17.559 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/Choreographer: Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-05-15 12:16:17.656 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:17.807 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:28.849 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
2020-05-15 12:16:28.849 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
2020-05-15 12:16:28.914 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:29.012 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:29.159 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:29.290 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:29.627 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:29.825 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:33.544 3814-3825/com.parsoni I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(128B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 25MB/25MB, paused 5.248ms total 21.323ms
2020-05-15 12:16:33.564 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:33.578 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 3814
2020-05-15 12:16:33.663 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
2020-05-15 12:16:33.663 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
2020-05-15 12:16:33.675 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js: Line 125 : Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fcontact.html&p1=-1&p2=
2020-05-15 12:16:33.675 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(125)] "Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fcontact.html&p1=-1&p2=", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js (125)
2020-05-15 12:16:33.720 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:33.740 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js: Line 11 : Transition Rejection($id: 1 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fcontact.html&p1=-1&p2=)
2020-05-15 12:16:33.740 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Transition Rejection($id: 1 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fcontact.html&p1=-1&p2=)", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js (11)
2020-05-15 12:16:33.851 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2020-05-15 12:16:33.948 3814-3814/com.parsoni D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js: Line 11 : Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fcontact.html&p1=-1&p2=
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:7:168
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:164:28
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:138:44
        at m.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:149:147)
        at m.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:152:525)
        at k (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:103:129)
        at V (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:108:205)
        at XMLHttpRequest.A.onerror (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:109:195)
2020-05-15 12:16:33.948 3814-3814/com.parsoni I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Error: [$templateRequest:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$templateRequest/tpload?p0=pages%2Fcontact.html&p1=-1&p2=
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:7:168
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:164:28
        at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:138:44
        at m.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:149:147)
        at m.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:152:525)
        at k (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:103:129)
        at V (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:108:205)
        at XMLHttpRequest.A.onerror (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:109:195)", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/angular-ui-router.min.js (11)
2020-05-15 12:16:34.013 3814-3814/com.parsoni W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

I believe that the app is not finding the files referenced in index.html, as the index.html Home tag is loaded, but the html and the controller present in the route file is not loaded.

Does anyone know what can cause this problem?

Any help is most welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to whitelist the url.

Install the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist
In config.xml add
`<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />`

to test it.

If it works i suggest you change * to a more specific address.

I suggest that you read the documentation

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maddoxswe.
The access origin line was already in the config.xml file, so it only includes the allow-navigation line.
But it didn't work for me.

I created a new simpler project and tried to build the apk. I noticed that index.html is loaded, but apparently the files listed in index.html are not. Because the style is not charged.

Any suggestions as to what it might be?

Comment: And did you try to install the whitelist plugin?

I think you get better output if you start the project with android studio and read the logcat output.

Comment: I removed all the links loaded externally, put everything inside my js folder, but nothing has changed. I applied the correction to the question.

Comment: Yes .. I installed the whitelist plugin.

Comment: Maxddoxswe, when you say "start the project with android studio", would you open the apk generated by cordova in Android Studio? Sorry for the doubts, but I don't know much about mobile development.

Comment: No, first you build the project with cordova build android. Then you can open the folder with android studio. It will recognize it as a android project. There you can run it in a emulator or on a real phone and see the output to find what happens.

So open Cordova project -> Android  in android studio.

Comment: I believe that changing the script will not solve it. Because my app.js is not in the js folder. I put in question the folder structure of my project.

Comment: I'll do the test with Android Studio to see if I can find the problem.

Comment: Maddoxswe, I tried your question of debugging the app through Android Studio. However, I couldn't identify the problem in the logcat. I posted the log on the question. Can you find the problem?

Comment: I found the problem.
I use the ui-router with html5 active.

Disabling html5 and changing the links (href="/" to href="#!/")in the href, the app works.

Now another question that I am researching about has arisen: is it possible to use the active html5 in any way with the cordova?